# Selenium Automation - Write text in mail

Tags: java, python, selenium, automation

I am trying to code a python program with Selenium which writes and sends a mail on the following website: http://www.laposte.net/accueil

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get("https://www.laposte.net/accueil")

pseudo = driver.find_element_by_name("login")
mdp = driver.find_element_by_name("password")

pseudo.send_keys("testselenium@laposte.net")
mdp.send_keys("Testselenium1")

pseudo.submit()

newmess = driver.find_element_by_id("zb__NEW_MENU")
newmess.click()

destinataire = driver.find_element_by_id("zv__COMPOSE-1_to_control")
destinataire.send_keys("adress@gmail.com")

objet = driver.find_element_by_id("zv__COMPOSE-1_subject_control")
objet.send_keys("Test selenium")

texte = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@class='mceContentBody']")
texte.send_keys("Test")
```

My code works, but I am unable to put some text in my body message.

I get this error: **Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath", "selector":"//body[@class='mceContentBody']"}**

For information, the HTML code of the text box is:

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody "     
onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('DWT48_content').onLoad.dispatch();" 
contenteditable="true" dir="LTR" style="font-family: &quot;times new 
roman&quot;, &quot;new york&quot;, times, serif; font-size: 14pt; color: 
rgb(0, 0, 0);"><div><br></div></body>
```

Would you have any idea to write some text in the mail?

Thanks.

Lcs

Comment: The editor may be in an `<iframe>` element, in which case, you’d need to switch to the frame first. However, I have a fundamental issue with using Selenium for automating sending of email. There are far better ways to automate that than going through a web-based email client, if your goal is to automate sending email.

Comment: I'm not planning to use this code for real purposes. It's just a way for me to get some knowledge with Selenium. 
Regarding the <iframe> element, would you have any idea how to handle it ? Shoud I use a xpath?

Answer (score 1):

On the second to last line you are writing:

```
texte = driver.find_element_id("tinymce")
```

Shouldn't the method-call instead be:

```
texte = driver.find_element_by_id("tinymce")
```

(note the "**by**")

Answer (score 0):

Is it because of some extra space at the end of class attribute?